# ASP.Net Core - EC2 to S3 file upload with Access Denied

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have developed a .NET Core 3.1 Web API which allows the users to upload their documents to S3 bucket. When I deploy the API to AWS ElasticBeansTalk EC2 instance and call the endpoint which uploads the file to S3, I get an error "Access Denied".

By the way, I have created IAM policy and role to give full access to S3 from my EC2 instance. I have also copied the .aws folder which contains credentials file onto the EC2 instance.

**API Controller Action**

```
public async Task<ApiResponse> UpdateProfilePic([FromBody]UploadProfilePicRequest model)
{
    using (Stream stream = model.profilePicData.Base64StringToStream(out string header))
    {
        var tags = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        var metaData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        metaData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{model.filename}\""));
        if (_host.IsDevelopment())
        {
            tags.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("public", "yes"));
        }
        await AmazonS3Uploader.UploadFileAsync(stream, "myDir/", model.fileId, tags, metaData);
    }
}
```

The *AmazonS3Helper* class shown below:

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UploderApp.Services
{
    public static class AmazonS3Uploader
    {

        private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.APSouth1;

        private static readonly IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(GetAwsCredentials(), bucketRegion);
        private static readonly string S3Bucket = "abc-test";


        private static AWSCredentials GetAwsCredentials()
        {
            var chain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();
            if (chain.TryGetAWSCredentials("MYPROFILE", out AWSCredentials awsCredentials))
            {
                return awsCredentials;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static async Task UploadFileAsync(Stream fileStream, string virtualDirectory, string keyName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client))
                {
                    //Upload data from a type of System.IO.Stream.
                    await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileStream, S3Bucket, virtualDirectory + keyName).ConfigureAwait(true);
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error encountered on server. Message:'{e.Message}' when writing an object");
            }
        }

        public static async Task UploadFileAsync(Stream stream, string virtualDirectory, string keyName, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> tags = null, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> metadata = null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Specify advanced settings.
                var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    BucketName = S3Bucket,
                    InputStream = stream,
                    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
                    Key = virtualDirectory + keyName
                };
                if (metadata != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in metadata)
                    {
                        fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                    }
                }
                if (tags != null)
                {
                    fileTransferUtilityRequest.TagSet = new List<Tag>();
                    foreach (var tag in tags)
                    {
                        fileTransferUtilityRequest.TagSet.Add(new Tag { Key = tag.Key, Value = tag.Value });
                    }
                }

                using (var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client))
                {
                    await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest).ConfigureAwait(true);
                }

            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error encountered on server. Message:'{e.Message}' when writing an object");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

However, if I create a console application and use the above class without any modifications, it uploads the file from the same EC2 instance.

Code from the *Main* function of my Console Application.

```
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var file = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/Screenshot.png";
        try
        {

            var tags = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            var metaData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            metaData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"profile-pic.png\""));

            using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
            {
                AmazonS3Uploader.UploadFileAsync(stream, "mydir/", "screenshot.png", tags, metaData).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }           
    }
```

This is very strange. Can anybody help me to understand the root cause, please?

**Edit:1**
Output of the `aws s3 ls s3://abc-test` is shown below
[image]

**Edit:2**
Uploading the EC2 folder to S3
[image: Upload EC2 Folder to S3]

Comment: Can you run this command from your ec2 and post results
"aws s3 ls s3://<awsexamplebucket>"
replace <> with your bucket. Also share your policy if issue persists

Comment: Screenshot attached. Please see Edit:1

Comment: So that proves your instance has access to s3, its not access issue. let me see your code

Comment: Can you do one more command to test. " aws s3 sync '<localfilepath>' s3://<awsexamplebucket>", please add a local file path in the command, and see weather it is uploaded on s3?

Comment: Pushed another screenshot